# DC motor lock controlled by H-bridge

Tags: h-bridge

I'm trying to control a DC motor by H-bridge in my board.
The motor works well by PWM signal but, in breaking mode, only the lower switches are on, motor is not locked completely.
When I turn the motor shaft by hand, the shaft moves easily, but not as easy as freewheeling, all switches are off.

I have MAXON motor controller, EPOS2.
I have tested the motor by EPOS2, but in lock mode, it is hard to turn the motor shaft.

How is the EPOS2 able to lock tightly?
I checked the motor's power line by oscilloscope, a very short duration PWM signal is on the power line, but the shaft is not turning.

When turning low speed, I can stop the motor by my hand, but on EPOS2, I can not do that.
I have to move the external load by motor in lower speed, but I think motor can not do that because lower torque for my board.
In my board, I can stop the motor shaft easily in low speed, also.

[image]

This is my schematic.
LTC4449 is N-channel MOSFET driver.
When L_PWM and R_PWM are low, Bottom Gate(BG) of LTC4449 are high, so Q3 and Q4 are on state.

Please advise me.

Comment: Coil current must not be turned off for holding or stop mode .  This controls brake torque.  You must figure out what switches that means

Comment: What H bridge are you using?  It's likely you have chosen an unsuitable one, though you may have other problems as well.

Comment: Is there anyone who give the hints? BR Paul